# Received Signal Error vs. BER

Tags: estimation, statistics, least-squares, equalizer

It is my understanding that the least squares algorithm (e.g., in equalization) minimizes the received signal error. However, minimizing the received signal error does not necessarily equate to minimizing the BER.

I was wondering why those two are not always equivalent? And how to properly gauge the performance of the least squares algorithm if BER is not the right metric?

*EDIT: Simulation description*

random bits --> frame bits --> NRZL --> modulator --> AWGN --> demodulator (integer multiple oversampled) --> LS EQ --> soft bits --> BER comparison

- modulator: FSK and BPSK (tried both)
- AWGN: Eb/No of 7dB - 20dB
- frame structure: 16-bit training sequence followed by 496 random bits
- Optionally add multipath delay as well (1-2 bauds).
- Taps on LS EQ 3-11 bauds.

Comment: My suggestion is to think very carefully about what you mean by "received signal error". Try to put it in mathematical terms (equations).

Comment: Can you expand on this please?

Comment: @BigBrownBear00: MBaz is trying to get you to think about what you believe that an equalizer does. Different equalizer structures optimize against different criteria, but they in general try to force some observable attribute of your signal toward a desired value. Depending on what that attribute is, and the characteristics of your channel, this may or may not result in the best BER performance. Least squares is just an optimization technique used to implement an equalizer; it doesn't actually dictate what criterion you're actually optmizing.

Comment: @JasonR I understand that, but my intuition leads me to believe that minimizing the received signal error will also minimize the bit error rate. I am having a hard time thinking of a scenario where that is not true..

Comment: @BigBrownBear00: What is your definition of "received signal error" though? Given an observation of a particular symbol from the channel, how do you calculate what its "error" is?

Comment: @JasonR I am using Stirling and Moon as my reference (they describe this process and use the term received signal error) - but my interpretation is when dealing with soft symbols, the euclidean distance

Comment: @BigBrownBear00: My point is, though, that the equalizer doesn't know the true value of the symbols, unless the data is known *a priori*. This can be useful for training the equalizer, but it doesn't accomplish the goal of transferring information. You have to use some criterion to decide what the error signal is. For instance, a *decision-directed* equalizer uses the Euclidean distance to the nearest valid symbol in the constellation as the error metric. You can design your equalizer to minimize this, but that doesn't guarantee minimum BER, as some of the decisions that it uses will be wrong.

Comment: @JasonR The least squares equalizer is not blind, since it is equalizing based on a desired response (which would be a sequence known a-priori). After demodulation you can reasonably calculate euclidean distance for +/- 1 to calculate received signal error. Maybe you are not minimizing BER b/c you are making wrong decisions at times, which makes sense. But in simulation sometimes I see BER higher than not using the LS equalizer - which is not what I expect.

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 could you describe your simulation (channel model, modulation, how LS is implemented, etc and maybe your code) by editting your question?

Comment: @AlexTP updated!

Comment: @BigBrownBear00: That is a pretty short training phase for your equalizer. It's not surprising that its performance would be inconsistent, as it's likely you aren't giving it time to achieve convergence; sometimes after the 16-bit training sequence, you have a decent set of equalizer taps and other times you don't. The RLS algorithm converges statistically; you aren't *guaranteed* that it will have achieved convergence after any particular length of time, especially such a brief period.

Comment: @JasonR is there a rule of thumb for how long the training sequence needs to be to see convergence? I tried going to 64-bits without seeing the results I expect

Comment: Convergence analysis of adaptive filters is a very complicated topic. I can't do it justice; I would recommend a good adaptive filter text, like *Adaptive Filter Theory* by Haykin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer on your question with this: Least Square equalizer is minimizing the intersymbol interference of your signal (ISI), between the symbols, which does not translate directly to minimization of the bit error rate. When I am saying 'directly' that means that there is no exact linear dependency between the error reduction in the equalizer, and the bit error rate. However, they generally tend to go into the same direction.

The reason for that is the nature of equalizer, as the nonlinear estimator.

The chain of processing that you have shown consist of processing modules, and some of them are nonlinear, which interferes with the bit error rate  minimization. In other words, bit error rate minimization is not a criterion that is used by the equalizer.

Below is the mass of papers that are talking about it, and it is not a simple matter.

Please note the first one: "Approximate Minimum Bit-Error Rate Equalization for Binary Signaling" which actually argues exactly the same line of inquiry that you are advocating: "Although most linear and decision-feedback equalizers are designed to minimize a mean-squared error (MSE) performance metric, the equalizer that directly minimizes biterror rate (BER) may signiﬁcantly outperform the minimum MSE equalizer".

This means that the digital bit error based criterion would be a better choice for reducing the bit error rate than the one that is typically used.

http://www.ijesit.com/Volume%202/Issue%203/IJESIT201303_07.pdf

https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/examples/ber-performance-of-different-equalizers.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

http://barry.ece.gatech.edu/pubs/conference/icc97.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. You clearly understood the nature of my question and provided helpful resources.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you.